# API Gateway logs: Amend name of log

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

When setting up logging for the API Gateway, the log created follows this default pattern :

API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_awsnameofservice/stage

The awsnamesofservice part is like 'fhsdydfn7*' an aws equivilent for the name of your service.  Is there a way to rename this, so it becomes something more user friendly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For execution logs for REST and WebSocket APIs, there is no way for you to configure this today.

For access logs you can provide the log group when you configure the logs by specifying the `destinationArn`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html